# problem with dmg file

Tags: macos

I have created a dmg file named try.dmg which contains an executable application myapplication.app together with a compiled library mylibrary.lib; I used Disk Utility in order to create the try.dmg file. I mounted the try.dmg file on my computer and I opened the application myapplication.app with no problems.

Still, I tried to do the same thing on another Macintosh, with the same operating system Mac OS X, but I got some problems: I mounted the try.dmg file and then when I tried to open the application myapplication.app I got an error message, that the application has quit unexpectedly.

Can someone explain me what is it happening? How come this try.dmg file can be mounted and the application can be opened with no problems on my computer with Mac OS X, but on another computer with Mac OS X, after I mount the try.dmg file I get errors when I try opening the application?

Thank you very much for your help.
Best wishes,
Madalina

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the app to another Mac without going via a .dmg file - it may be an unrelated problem - e.g. you built a debug version with ZeroLink enabled, or you have a dependency on some non-standard framework, or you built against the 10.6 SDK and tried to run on a 10.5 machine.

Also try looking at the CrashReporter logs (in Console.app) on the target machine for more info as to why the app failed to launch.